# TeeChart Compact Framework support

Tags: teechart

I'm looking at using the TeeChart library for Compact Framework AND Full Framework (3.5) I'd like to know if there are any differences in API to support both platforms from the same source?  (my current charting lib, different vendor, is not supported on Win32)

Question for Steema Software: I can't find the teechart.pocket.dll in the evaluation download? are you dropping CFNet support? where to get a cf eval dll?

Answer (score 0):

No API differences between both versions, except for those specific to each platform.

Compact Framework and ReportingServices assemblies are currently not being included in the production version of TeeChart unless future customer demand signals its need. That's because CF doesn't work with .NET Framework 4.0 and 4.5 which means it doesn't compile with Visual Studio 2010 and Visual Studio 2012. In the meantime we are prepared to work with any customer that demands the assemblies on a case by case basis to certify its compatibility and featureset. In the meantime, you can use the assemblies included with previous versions.